# php html on click event not working when json

Tags: javascript

jQuery onclick not working for added element from ajax call,

i am using onclick handler for my appication and using php for loading data dynamically

php html on click event not working when json

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added content, you need to follow below format

```
$('body').on('click', '.target', function() {});
```